# Is it possible to move Aspect class for logging in a multi app or micro service architecture to a common place or repo?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, aspect

I have a common repo for frequently used services/code and in the multi service I have a write separate Aspect class for logging request, controller or service classes. What I wanted to check if there is a way to move this to a code to common repo and inject that dependency for reusability.

Example :
app 1 -  class :Aspect1.java

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* com.test.app1.controller..*.*(..))")
public void allControllerMethods() {
}
```

app 2 -  class :Aspect2.java

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* com.test.app2.controller..*.*(..))")
public void allControllerMethods() {
}
```

framework repo - move the code from app1, app2, etc to common framework repo

Comment: of course it is possible, check the the following on how to create this apps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64554436/deploying-a-spring-boot-project-using-maven-and-further-importing-it-in-other-pr

Comment: @Aman I am already using the library for common code like Splunk friendly code and Spring sleuth, here my question is specific to Aspect way of logging, as the Spring container will be separate for each of the apps and way it manages beans and how will the library identify the "@Pointcut" of some other Spring service say app1 that was called by user and now it run that method. If you have any example of this let me know.

Comment: You are right that they run in different context. Once you have created a separate app(common functionalities), you have to scan the components in the inheriting app. IMHO, if it is only for this aspect, I would duplicate it in both apps

Comment: If the pointcut matches the relevant applications or micro-services, I see no problem. A separate aspect library is just like any other dependency. Just make sure component scan in your target application picks up the aspect package(s) and that Spring AOP is actually activated.

Comment: @kriegaex, excited to hear that it is doable, could you please elaborate a bit more or could point me to some example.

Comment: With all due respect, it is your job to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing your situation, then I can help you fix it. But first I need to be able to find the root cause. So I would appreciate a minimal, but full sample project on GitHub, ideally a Maven project or Gradle as the next best choice (I am a Maven guy).  With the two code snippets given, I really cannot analyse anything because it is not the information I need.